I can't overfit Resnet50 to map a single image to its corresponding set of 1000 (x,y) points. Why?
I have a 360p image: https://imgur.com/a/u3uDFj9
I have a corresponding human mask and a (1000,2) output, i.e, 1000 two dimensional points: https://file.io/Vc4hA1LYd5NO
My dataset actually has a huge pairs of these images and points. The idea is to get the neural network to learn the point initialization from an input image/mask. All the points corresponding to each image are within the mask, so there is definitely structure for a neural network to learn.
My initial problem was that all the points were being output at the dead center of the image, i.e, an average. This stackoverflow post talks about this issue but I couldn't benefit from anything stated there for my problem.
I tried to make the model overfit just on one image as well but it does not seem to work. I tried different loss functions, and different pre and post processing of model outputs.

I primarily used a Resnet50 model for this experimentation with a modified fully connected layer at the end
I normalized the input image with the same mean and std stated on pytorch documentation for resnet50
Since all points in ground truth are between (-1,1), I tried to use a tanh activation at the output layer. I also tried using Sigmoid in case there's a vanishing gradient problem with tanh and normalized that model output back to [-1,1] range before loss computation.
I tried to freeze and unfreeze all the resnet50 layers during optimization.

None of this seems to work for me. I would like to see if someone can get this working on a single data point that I have included.
